# jssor slider not responding to nav arrows

Tags: javascript, jssor

I am building a jssor slider dynamically using javascript. The slider is based on the jssor 'carousel' demo. Everything looks correct when displayed, including the navigation arrows at either end of the slider. It will also respond correctly when I swipe left or right with the mouse. The slider, however, does not respond to any clicks on the nav arrows.

One problem I have seen mentioned in other postings is improper nesting of the nav arrows. I don't think that is the problem here. Any help would be most appreciated.

Here is the javascript that builds the slider:

```
var CpxRowSlider = function(callback) {
var callback;
var indexedImgEl = new Array();
var DEFAULT_H = 110;
var DEFAULT_W = 260;
var outerDivEl = document.createElement('div');
var title = true;
var addNavArrows = true;

var sliderDivEl = null;
var sliderId = "slider_SOLO";

/*
 * image set should be an array of key-value pairs where the value is the
 * URL of an image and the key will be used as a tag that identifies the
 * image in any callback functions.
 */
function create(imageSet) {
    /* Slides Container -- */
    var rowDivEl = document.createElement('div');
    $(rowDivEl).attr("u", "slides");
    $(rowDivEl).css({
        "cursor" : "move",
        "position" : "absolute",
        "left" : "0px",
        "top" : "0px",
        "width" : "780px",
        "height" : "110px",
        "overflow" : "hidden"
    });
    for ( var key in imageSet) {
        var imgUrl = imageSet[key];
        var imgDivEl = document.createElement('div');
        var imgEl = document.createElement('img');
        imgEl.src = imgUrl;
        $(imgEl).attr("u", "image");
        imgDivEl.appendChild(imgEl);
        // add to row
        rowDivEl.appendChild(imgDivEl);
        $(imgEl).data("cpxKey", key);
        /*
         * actions associated with the img....
         */
        /*
         * click event gets handed off via callback
         */
        if ((callback != undefined) && (callback != null)) {
            imgEl.onclick = function(evt) {
                var targetImg = evt.target;
                trace("Click on " + $(targetImg).data("cpxKey"));
                callback($(targetImg).data("cpxKey"));
            };
        }
    }
    // add slides to a slider...
    sliderDivEl = document.createElement('div');
    sliderDivEl.id = sliderId

    $(sliderDivEl).css({
        "position" : "relative",
        "left" : "0px",
        "top" : "0px",
        "width" : "780px",
        "height" : "110px"
    });
    // add to DOM
    sliderDivEl.appendChild(rowDivEl);
    if (addNavArrows) {
        sliderDivEl.appendChild(createNavArrow(true));
        sliderDivEl.appendChild(createNavArrow(false));
    }
    outerDivEl.appendChild(sliderDivEl);
}

function createNavArrow(toLeft) {
    var arrowSpan = document.createElement('span');
    $(arrowSpan).attr("u", "image");
    $(arrowSpan).css({
        "top" : "30px",
        "width" : "55px",
        "height" : "55px"
    });
    if (toLeft) {
        $(arrowSpan).css({
            "left" : "5px"
        });

        $(arrowSpan).addClass("jssora03l");
    } else {
        $(arrowSpan).css({
            "right" : "5px"
        });
        $(arrowSpan).addClass("jssora03r");
    }
    return arrowSpan;
}

/*
 * Invoked only AFTER the slider has been added to the DOM
 */
function finalize() {
    // add to sliders being controlled by jssor
    var sliderOptions = getSliderOptions();
    var jssor_sliderh = new $JssorSlider$(sliderId, sliderOptions);
}

function getSliderOptions() {
    var sliderhOptions = {
        /*
         * $AutoPlay [Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow,
         * this option must be set to true, default value is false
         */
        $AutoPlay : false,
        /*
         * $PauseOnHover [Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a
         * slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause
         * for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default
         * value is 1
         */
        $PauseOnHover : 1,
        /*
         * $AutoPlaySteps [Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request
         * (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default
         * value is 1
         */
        $AutoPlaySteps : 2,
        /*
         * $ArrowKeyNavigation [Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key)
         * navigation or not, default value is false
         */
        // $ArrowKeyNavigation : true,
        /*
         * [Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in
         * milliseconds, default value is 500
         */
        $SlideDuration : 300,
        /*
         * [Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value
         * is 20
         */
        $MinDragOffsetToSlide : 20,
        /*
         * [Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width
         * of 'slides' container
         */
        $SlideWidth : DEFAULT_W,
        /*
         * [Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is
         * height of 'slides' container
         */
        // $SlideHeight: 150,
        /*
         * [Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
         */
        $SlideSpacing : 3,
        /*
         * [Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be
         * disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default
         * value is 1
         */
        $DisplayPieces : 3,
        /*
         * [Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys
         * only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
         */
        $ParkingPosition : 0,
        /*
         * [Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1)
         * to search UI components (slides container, loading screen,
         * navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail
         * navigator container etc).
         */
        $UISearchMode : 0,
        // ...................................
        // [Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
        $BulletNavigatorOptions : {
            $Class : $JssorBulletNavigator$, // [Required] Class to
            // create navigator instance
            $ChanceToShow : 1, // [Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2
            // Always
            $AutoCenter : 0, // [Optional] Auto center navigator in
            // parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2
            // Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
            $Steps : 1, // [Optional] Steps to go for each navigation
            // request, default value is 1
            $Lanes : 1, // [Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items,
            // default value is 1
            $SpacingX : 0, // [Optional] Horizontal space between each item
            // in pixel, default value is 0
            $SpacingY : 0, // [Optional] Vertical space between each item
            // in pixel, default value is 0
            $Orientation : 1
        // [Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2
        // vertical, default value is 1
        }
    }
    return sliderhOptions;
}

function trace(msg) {
    console.log("CpxRowSlider: " + msg);
}

return {
    create : create,
    finalize : finalize,
    getContainer : function() {
        return outerDivEl;
    }
};
};
```

UPDATE: 
Well, some digging around turned up the "where" but the "why" is still a mystery. The generated HTML should look something like this (minus the "styles" for clarity):

```
<div id="slider_SOLO" >      
        <div u="slides">
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../foo1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../foo2.jpg" />
            </div>
        <div>
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora03l" ></span>
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora03r"></span>
</div>
```

The problem is that in the actual HTML page there are TWO  elements with the attribute u="slides". The 2nd is the correct one but just before it is another empty div. In other words, the DOM I see when I examine the displayed HTML is more like:

```
<div id="slider_SOLO" >     
        <div u="slides"></div>   
        <div u="slides">
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../foo1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../foo2.jpg" />
            </div>
        <div>
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora03l" ></span>
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora03r"></span>
</div>
```

If I add a similar div to the jssor carousel demo HTML, I get the same behavior (i.e., navigation arrows no longer work).

The problem is that the error (i.e., the extra DIV) is not inserted by my javascript. Rather it seems to be linked to the call
 `var jssor_sliderh = new $JssorSlider$(sliderId, sliderOptions);`

I am wondering if the cause is something in the options I pass in.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! The root cause was indeed my options but not in the way I thought. I was missing the $ArrowNavigatorOptions. The mystery DIV is still being inserted but everything now works correctly.

The take-away lesson for me is that jssor seems to fail quietly in the sense that rather than generate a console message about the missing option it simply did nothing.

Comment: You are right! I will add this option check for later update.